Issues with Guava upgrade
Recently upgraded the google guava jar from version 30.1.1.jre to version 33.3.0.jre to avoid CVE-2023-2976
This resulted in failure of some very old selenium. What next steps can i take to fix this?
error: method until in class FluentWait<T> cannot be applied to given types;
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(locator)));
             ^
   required: Function<? super WebDriver,V>
   found:    ExpectedCondition<WebElement>
   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
     (argument mismatch; ExpectedCondition<WebElement> cannot be converted to Function<? super WebDriver,V>)
   where V,T are type-variables:
     V extends Object declared in method <V>until(Function<? super T,V>)
     T extends Object declared in class FluentWait

